# How to call a function on a specific element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hey I'm looking to call a function on this 'add' element automatically and without the click?

```
  $(document).on('click', '.add', function() {
       $(this).parent().parent().addClass('appended');     
      }
```

So when the document loads the function will trigger on the 'add' element automatically without need to click it.

This question is very simple I know but I can't articulate what I meant to Google after trying several times.

Comment: use `$('.add').click()`

Comment: `$('.add').parent().parent().addClass('appended')`

Comment: So, you mean you unable to ask this same question on google, but you are able to create a question on SO without any issues?

Comment: Why so many steps? Why not just do the action you want on load? Why load > click something > then action?

Comment: thanks guys really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery, you can perform actions upon loading the DOM by using a *document.ready* block. Anything within this block will be executed upon DOM load.

You also have the ability to loop through any amount of selector (your desired class in this case) and perform any amount of actions you desire. This function is the `.each()` function.

**Example:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add').each(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass('appended');
    });
});
```

Comment: No need for `.each()` here

Comment: It was the first solution that popped into my mind. I wouldn't be surprised if there are other, simpler methods of achieving the same results. If you want, we can edit the answer to contain other solutions as well for future readers. I'd be happy to edit it and quote you for credit @j08691